# How can I efficiently sample a raster with points in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to use Earth Engine to sample raster data via points and save that information to a local file. Currently I do this by creating a `FeatureCollection` of point geometries and then pass that structure to a `reduceRegions` call. I iterate over the result of `getInfo` to get the sampled raster data. However, the runtime of this function is much much slower than I would have expected. Is there any way to get runtime feedback about a job that is being processed on GEE, or a better way to asynchronously request jobs for a client side download?

This is a simplified, but functional, version of what I'm trying to do that takes 30ish seconds the first time I run it. My actual data includes thousands of points and the wait time makes me wonder if I've done something wrong.

```
import ee


def main():
    """Entry point."""
    ee.Initialize()

    pts = ee.FeatureCollection([
      ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-118.6010, 37.0777])),
      ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-118.5896, 37.0778])),
      ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-118.5842, 37.0805])),
      ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-118.5994, 37.0936])),
      ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-118.5861, 37.0567]))
    ])

    img = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_8DAY_NDVI").filterDate('1997-01-01', '2019-01-01')
    mean_img = img.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
    samples = mean_img.reduceRegions(**{
        'collection': pts,
        'scale': 30,
        'reducer': 'mean'}).getInfo()  #  <<< takes a long time to run! better way to do this?
    for sample in samples['features']:
        print(f"{sample['geometry']['coordinates']}, {sample['properties']['mean']}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I asked this question on stackoverflow but voted to close it because I think this is the correct site for it (https://stackoverflow.com/q/69531091/42897)

Answer (score 2):

The collection you're starting from is a computed collection and the result of each 8 day mosaic is a global image.  That means creating the mean image you're using involves every image in the collection from 1997 to 2019, even though you're only using a small portion of each image.

You would get much better performance by computing the NDVI yourself, so you can apply a filterBounds to the lower-level collection and limit the images involved.

```
expr = "ndvi = clamp(float(b('B4') - b('B3')) / (b('B4') + b('B3')), -1, 1)"

img = (ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA")
       .filterDate('1997-01-02', '2019-01-01')
       .filterBounds(pts.geometry().bounds())
       .map(lambda img : img.expression(expr)))
mean_img = img.select('ndvi').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
```

That said, neither approach is accounting for clouds or cloud shadows, so the mean NDVI computed this way isn't particularly valid.